# Extracting data from at multiple nested json file from bigquery

Tags: sql, json, google-bigquery, nested, unnest

I have been looking for a way to unnest a nested json file from my bigquery -> result being that I came one level deeper in the nested json file using json_extract_scalar as well as trying to unnest after the fact. I want to extract the PriceId from this nested from BQ.

`"data":  "{\"Plan\": [{\"Features\": [], \"PriceId\": \"Monthly\", \"Id\": \"xyz\", \"bool\": false}]`

Alternatively a solution for the sql query `cast(data ->> 'Plan' as varchar(10000) as plan`

Trying to use json_query/query_array/extract/extract_scalar in the same way as:

`select json_query_array(data, '$.Plan') from table`

only gets me to this point:

`{\"Features\": [], \"PriceId\": \"Monthly\", \"Id\": \"xyz\", \"bool\": false}`

Here my problem isnt that i cant parse that in another program -- the problem is that the data cant be parsed due to the BQ string limit is exceeded when loaded in another program such as alteryx.

NOTE that the entire "data" is type STRING in Bigquery.

Hoping for some help to unnest the nested json here as I am currently stuck.
Thanks in advance

Comment: SELECT JSON_EXTRACT_SCARLAR(data, '$.Plan[0].PriceId') as PriceId
FROM table

did the trick